# MySQL Trigger with IF statement on UPDATE

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I wish to create a trigger.

These are my two tables,

1. `kk_settlements` table

   ```
   | paidBy | paidTo | settlementAmount | createdAt | groupId |
   ```
2. `kk_user_relations` table

   ```
   | userId | userId_1 | groupId | amount |
   ```

Now when there is an `INSERT` on `kk_settlements` I want to create trigger and `UPDATE` `kk_user_relations` table.

Before doing an `UPDATE` I want to check if the `paidBy` is less that or greater than `paidTo` and based on that find the row in `kk_user_relations` table which is to be updated. (Since all rows in `kk_user_relations` are stored by `userId` < `userId_1`

I have tried adding the following `trigger` (I am using phpmyadmin)

```
IF (paidBy < paidTo)
THEN
UPDATE kk_user_relations 
SET kk_user_relations.amount = kk_user_relations.amount + settlementAmount 
WHERE kk_user_relations.userId = paidBy 
AND kk_user_relations.userId_1 = paidTo 
AND kk_user_relations.groupId = groupId;
ELSE
UPDATE kk_user_relations 
SET kk_user_relations.amount = kk_user_relations.amount + settlementAmount 
WHERE kk_user_relations.userId_1 = paidBy
AND kk_user_relations.userId = paidTo 
AND kk_user_relations.groupId = groupId;
END IF
```

This `trigger` does not work and throws an error.

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'paidBy' in 'field list'
```

The complete `trigger` generated by phpmyadmin is

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `kk_update_user_relations`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `kk_update_user_relations`
AFTER INSERT ON `kk_settlements`
FOR EACH ROW 
IF (paidBy < paidTo) THEN 
UPDATE kk_user_relations 
SET kk_user_relations.amount = kk_user_relations.amount + settlementAmount 
WHERE kk_user_relations.userId = paidBy
AND kk_user_relations.userId_1 = paidTo 
AND kk_user_relations.groupId = groupId;
ELSE UPDATE kk_user_relations 
SET kk_user_relations.amount = kk_user_relations.amount + settlementAmount 
WHERE kk_user_relations.userId_1 = paidBy 
AND kk_user_relations.userId = paidTo 
AND kk_user_relations.groupId = groupId;
END IF
```

Where am I going wrong? I suppose the I am going wrong while using `paidBy` and `paidTo` in the trigger. Please correct me.

Also suggest if there is a better way of getting the same thing done. I am open for suggestions.

Comment: Try `NEW.paidBy` and `NEW.paidTo`. That is how you reference the values for the current row of `FOR EACH ROW`; in an UPDATE trigger you can use `OLD` and `NEW` to refer to the previous value of the field and the one it is being changed to.

Comment: @Uueerdo Thanks for quick reply! I used `NEW` to refer the values of `paidBy` and `paidTo`, it works now!

Thanks a lot for the comment! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try NEW.paidBy and NEW.paidTo.

That is how you reference the values for the current row of FOR EACH ROW. In an UPDATE trigger you can use OLD and NEW to refer to the previous value of the field and the one it is being changed to.